# counting visits in class based view. declaring it in model

Tags: python, django

is there easier way to count the number of visits to the post in class based view?

```
class Post(models.Model):
        views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
   class PostListByMostViewedView(ListView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'community/mostviewed_home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
        context_object_name = 'posts'
        ordering = ['-views']
        paginate_by = 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no easier way  . you need a third-party app django-analytical. or if you want to track user manually define a model on link base or model base . and update it on view execution

Comment: is there a way to declare a function regard this in models.py and not modify class based view?

Comment: sure . you can declare multiple number of function on model. but you need to patch it with models any default function which call automatically. like model save function called every time model instance save. there are sever hook you can put you function.